# Postgresql query where statement positions

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables that I want to join. It works without where conditions. After adding where conditions, I got syntax error near `a` (where I give table1 an alternative name). From my understanding, the syntax looks correct?

My query

```
select * from table1 where date >= '2020-10-01' and date <= '2020-10-31' a
  left join table2 b where registered >= '2020-10-01' and registered <= '2020-10-31' b
      on a.id = cast(b.id as varchar)
```

Comment: No, it is nonsense. The WHERE clause should be at the end. (and the a is not expected here)

Comment: what if I want to give abbreviation to the two tables, what's the correct syntax

Comment: 1) there is **only one** WHERE clause. 2) JOIN is an **operator**, operating on table(expression)s 3) within a table expression, a table *can* have an alias. 4) `date` is a bad name for a column, since it is a key word.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- `where` goes after all tables (and their join conditions)
- aliases go immediately after the table name

Applying these two corrections and some formatting:

```
select *
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.id = cast(b.id as varchar)
  and registered >= '2020-10-01' and registered <= '2020-10-31'
where date >= '2020-10-01' and date <= '2020-10-31'
```

Conventionally, join conditions that describe access to joined rows (typically the keys) are coded first, then filtering conditions (ones involving only columns in the joined table) are coded last.

---

Which can be slightly simplified using `between` to:

```
select *
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.id = cast(b.id as varchar)
  and registered between '2020-10-01' and '2020-10-31'
where date between '2020-10-01' and '2020-10-31'
```